# SQL partition over - Invalid use of an aggregate function

Tags: sql

I have an issue, and peeled it down to the following simple code:

```
SELECT KUNDE_PART_REF
FROM G00V.G79_KUNDE_KONTAKT_INFO_NL_CBT g79A 
where  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KUNDE_PART_REF ORDER BY KUNDE_PART_REF ) = 1
```

Error:

> Error during Prepare  42903(-120)[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0120N
> Invalid use of an aggregate function or OLAP function.  SQLSTATE=42903
> (0,00 secs)

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logically speaking](https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/), `ROW_NUMBER` is calculated *few steps after* the `WHERE` clause so it cannot be used over there. You must use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT KUNDE_PART_REF
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KUNDE_PART_REF ORDER BY KUNDE_PART_REF) AS rn
    FROM G00V.G79_KUNDE_KONTAKT_INFO_NL_CBT
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the `ROW_NUMBER()` in a *derived table* (i.e. in a FROM clause subquery).

```
SELECT KUNDE_PART_REF
FROM (
    SELECT KUNDE_PART_REF,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KUNDE_PART_REF ORDER BY KUNDE_PART_REF) RN
    FROM G00V.G79_KUNDE_KONTAKT_INFO_NL_CBT g79A) as DT
where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the row_number() result first and then apply the where clause.